# summing two matrixes each one in a different file

Tags: awk, files, array

i have 2 files each contains like the following:

file 1:

> data : [
>   56, 34, 23, 54,
>   90, 234, 53, 12
>   ]

file 2:

> data : [
>   42, 56, 23, 98,
>   90, 23, 53, 32
>   ]

i want to sum 1st value from file 1 with the 1st value from file 2 and 2nd one with the 2nd one and so on and so on.

so the file3 should be like this :

> data : [
>   98, 90, 46, 152,
>   ...
>   ]

how can i achieve something like this

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ',? ' '
    {
        for(i=4;i!="]";i++)
            A[i]=$i
        getline file2
        printf("%s %s %s ", $1, $2, $3)
        i--
        for(j=4;j<i;j++)
            printf("%d, ", $j + A[j])
        print $j + A[j++], $j
    }
    ' file1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paste file1 file2 | tr '[],:' '    ' |
perl -lane '
   my($b, $e) = grep { $F[$_] eq "data" } 0 .. $#F;
   print
      join $",
         qw/data : [/,
         join(", ", map { $F[$_] + $F[$_+$e-$b] } $b+1 .. $e-1),
         q/]/,
      ;
' > file3
```

## Output

```
data : [ 98, 90, 46, 152, 180, 257, 106, 44 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk as one line (splitted here in two lines for readability):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]+"}NR!=FNR{printf("%s","data : [ ")} \
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (NR==FNR) {a[i]=$i} else {printf("%s%s", (a[i]+$i), (i==NF)?" ]\n":",")}}' file5 file6
data : [ 98,90,46,152,180,257,106,44 ]
```

This uses the FPAT method to define the fields instead of FS.

FS is used usually to define what the fields does not contain, while FPAT is used to define what the fields does contain.

File5 and File6 contain your input data:

```
$ cat file5
data :  [ 56, 34, 23, 54, 90, 234, 53, 12 ]
$ cat file6
data : [ 42, 56, 23, 98, 90, 23, 53, 32 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[^0-9]+' '
# output prefix
BEGIN {
   printf "data : [ "
}
# read first file
NR == FNR {
  for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) {
    a[i] = $i
  }
}
# read second file, output list of sums
NR != FNR {
  for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) {
    printf sep $i + a[i]
    sep = ", "
  }
}
# output suffix
END {
  print " ]"
}
' file1 file2
```